# Swift how to load an HTML page with URL that contains #

Tags: html, xcode, swift, url, load

The URL address I want to load the HTML page from ends with "`#2`".
My problem is that the every time it loads page 1 instead (`#1`).

Why does that happens?

```
func getUrl ( Page: Int) -> String
{ 
    let myUrlString="http://www.amazon.de/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/530887031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_1_kinc#2"
    if let myURL = NSURL(string: myUrlString)
    {
    var error: NSError?
    let myHTMLString: NSString?
    do { myHTMLString = try NSString(contentsOfURL: myURL, encoding: NSISOLatin1StringEncoding) }

    catch let error1 as NSError
    {
    error = error1
    myHTMLString = nil
    }

    if let error = error    { print("Error !!: \(error)", terminator: "") }
    else                    {
                              HTMLPage=String(myHTMLString)
                              //print("HTML : \(myHTMLString)")
                            }
    }
    else { print("Error 123: \(myUrlString) doesn't seem to be a valid URL", terminator: "") }

    return (HTMLPage)
}
```

Comment: you need to add percent escapes to your string `"yourLink".stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters( NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!`

Comment: thanks for your response. I have checked it but it doesn't work. the modified url is http://www.amazon.de/gp/bestsellers/books/287480/ref=zg_bs_nav_b_1_b%232. If I put this url direct in the safari browser I get page 1

Answer (score 0):

Franc, unfortunately there's no way this is going to work. If you open the link in your browser and look closely, you'll see it loads page 1, but very quickly a spinner shows up and loads page 2.

**This happens because** the pagination is controlled via **JavaScript/Ajax**. The browser fires up the pagination event, so retrieving and parsing the page HTML will never get you to page 2 (or further).

Also the `#` character in a URL is mostly used to link to page anchors and JavaScript/Ajax status control, which in this case is the pagination. Both events are client-side (fired up by the web browser), so "fetching" the page HTML doesn't trigger such events.

---

#### That's sad, but what can be done?

Why are you fetching the page HTML, anyways? Amazon has an [extensive API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html) and most likely it will be able to provide the data you want, if what you're looking for is resulting products for a specific search.

I recommend you to take a look into Amazon API and you'll probably find it's much easier to accomplish whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand it has nothing to do with Swift.